# Exporting or creating a duplicate copy of the Data Extension with 2.6 billion records in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have tried exporting the 2.6 billion records using Data Extract activity however, it is failing. I created SQL which is timing out.
Later on, I created an Automation with 50 SQL queries and it is failing too:

```
Select sq.* 
FROM
(
select  a.*,
Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY a.TRANS_DETAIL_SQNC_NBR, a.SKU_KEY ASC) as Rowidentifier

from ENT.UA_POS_TRANS_DTL a
) sq

where sq.Rowidentifier BETWEEN  1 AND 20000000
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case you would need to increment by date ranges.  So long as you have a date field defined on your data extension this should be possible.  Due to the sheer data size you will run into execution time limits that are made to protect the database that an account lives on within Data Extract Activities/Query Activities/anything that is done to pull this data.  Your follow up steps would be:

1. Identify the maximum possible date range that consistently completes by query activity
2. You would start at the minimum date range that you were looking to pull `Select min(DateField) from ENT.UA_POS_TRANS_DTL`.   If you were unable to execute this to confirm what the date was then you would just have to determine what date you wanted to start at.  An example would be something like this:

   select Field1, Field2, Field3 from ENT.UA_POS_TRANS_DTL a where DateField > 'InsertDate1' and DateField < 'InsertDate2'
3. Then you would follow up by utilizing your upper limit of your date range (you would start at the maximum value then repeat)

   select Field1, Field2, Field3 from ENT.UA_POS_TRANS_DTL a where DateField >= 'InsertDate2' and DateField < 'InsertDate3'

Ideally you would have a way to cycle through these in a fashion that didn't require a new query activity to be manually made each time.  These queries could also be sped up by not bringing over data that you do not need within the data extension that has 2.6 million records(such as not bringing over unnecessary fields).  You would also have to specifically define data extensions where you kept much smaller partitions of the data so that you did not end up with a large unusable data extension as a result of your queries.

This is a common resulting case of data extensions that do not have [retention/deprecation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_manage_data_extension_policies.htm&type=5) strategies implemented upon their initial creation.

[Additional Data Retention information](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000336497&type=1&mode=1).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you with one of my data extension.

Do you have a field "created date" or something that matches with a technical date ?

In order to avoid the timeout, I retrieved rows by month for example. The idea is to find the right volume to not reach the timeout. It works for me.

I hope it helps.

Regards,
Pierre.

Comment: There is a hidden field _createdDate in every data extension row which you can use in queries.

Comment: Thank you for the tips :)

Comment: I did a quick test and the field _createdDate does not exist...Did you ask something to the support to "activate" it ?

Comment: You're right. I just checked as well. This was a misinformation, I cannot reproduce. Interesting ... sorry!

Comment: _createdDate will exist on DEs that have data retention turned on, but is not on all DEs.

Comment: You're right, it works ! Thank you Mark DeHaven